# In geometry nodes, how do I move my instance relative to another instance?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a main instance and a sub instance. I'd like to move my sub instance relative to the main instance. How is it done?

[image: reference image]

Right now, when I add `Set Position` node to the "sub" instance, it moved relative to the world. I tried to use the tangent and normal outputs but I'm getting different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector rotate do this.

You can rotate instances around initial position using this setup:

[image]

To make initial position in radial symmetry, add this node like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Full set-up:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! This is exactly what I'm trying for. Thanks, Crantisz! I thought of Euler but I'm missing a lot of other nodes to make it work. Thanks so much! Learned a lot again :)

Comment: You should understand what does it mean, vector (normal for example) and Euler. They seem to be similar - 3 float components and explain direction, but they are very different and uses different nodes to manipulate with.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to combine the sub object with the main object before distributing them in the circle like this:

[image: Moving sub object relative to main object]

That way any transformation you apply to the sub object will be in the local space by default. If you have to use separate instance to points nodes for another reason then you might be able to do something with the attribute capture node and the index node but I'm not sure exactly how to go about that.

Comment: thanks for the answer :D my example is a bit too simplified so joining them may be the best solution. But if there isn't really any other way to transform another instance based on another instance, I guess I'll have to accept your answer :)  I'll wait a bit more for others :)